# How can my standalone php file recieve data from ajax post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So i have 3 files. Header.php, script.js and load_more.php. Header.php is normal header page on website, script.js is a file that gets called and makes ajax requests. load_more.php is the php file the script in script.js calls.

header.php: I get page Id($schoolofficialId) and put it into javascript variable to be accessed in script.js ajax data:

```
<?php
// There is more code to this but I do get the page ID and put it into $schoolOfficialId so this does work
    $shcoolOfficialId = $specificSchool[0]["id"];
?>

<!--Down in the <head> of the DOM where scripts get included-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var schoolId = <?php Print($shcoolOfficialId); ?>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
```

script.js: where ajax call is made. The second ajax request does work but I'm getting confused on the first ajax I want to push that js variable schoolId to load_more.php

```
            // execute an ajax query to push id of page to load_more.php
            $.ajax({
                url: 'load_more.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {schoolId:schoolId},
                success:function(data){

                }
            });
            // execute an ajax query to load more statements
            $.ajax({
                url: 'load_more.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {last_id:last_id, limit:limit},
                success:function(data){
                    // now we have the response, so hide the loader
                    $('#loader').hide();
                    // append: add the new statments to the existing data
                    $('#items').append(data);
                    // set is_loading to false to accept new loading
                    is_loading = false;
                }
            });
```

load_more.php: since my application is getting bigger I need to do switch statements so that is why I need the js variable schoolId to bring me the current page id or $schoolOfficialId in the php code in header.php: NOTE: I DO NOT WANT TO INCLUDE LOAD_MORE.PHP INTO MY DOM SO IT'S A STANDALONE PHP FILE:

```
// including the config file
require('config.php');
//pdo connct for config.php file
$pdo = connect();

var_dump($schoolId);
//this var dump returns NULL
switch ($schoolId) {
  case 1:
     echo "first school";
    break;

  case 2:
     echo "second school";
    break;
  default:
     //this default ends up happening because the $schoolId is NULL
     echo "no school";
    break;
}
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear What exactly is your loadmore.php file and what do you mean "I don't want to include it into my DOM?" PHP is server side code and DOM means Document Object Model. That's usually the HTML converted into a node tree in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Your `schoolId` is in fact `null`, because you cannot echo out a php value (*like the one you've done*) in JS. I'd recommend you to ***use a hidden input field*** in your html and *echo out* the value in the input's `value` attribute, then get the value using jQuery.

```
 <!-- In your html code -->
 <input type='hidden' id='schoolOfficialId' value='<?php echo $schoolOfficialId; ?>' />
```

Then afterwards, you can get the value of that input as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
        var schoolId = $('#schoolOfficialId').val(); //now you do have the value of the schoolOfficialId variable here.
   });

</script>
```

*Note the `$(function() ...` line, which means, the script is to be loaded **after** the document is ready.*

Comment: Ah ok I see, i followed what you did and it worked but I still have the same error with the first ajax call. My console.log error says: Uncaught ReferenceError: schoolId is not defined. on line 16 which is the data:{schoolId:schoolId} part. What can be the problem there?

Comment: Have you followed the call to ajax _after_ the `schoolId` variable was initialized? console.log `schoolId` in the beginning of the script (as in the anwser) to see if it has the expected value.

Comment: So i get the id with this ```var schoolId = $('#schoolOfficialId').val();``` and then convert it to integer with this: ```var schoolId2 = parseInt(schoolId);```. I even go into my console and check the variable schoolId2 and it outputs the id but now I cannot get it to my load_more.php; My ajax data looks like this: data: ```{schoolId:schoolId2}``` and load_more.php :```if (isset($_GET['schoolId'])) {
    echo "yessss";
}else {
    echo "nope";
}``` it keeps outputting nope :(

Comment: If you send data through AJAX _with_ **POST** method, you can only access it with `$_POST` array and NOT `$_GET`. Try changing it to see if it is defined now. Meanwhile, you _do not need to convert_ `schoolId` to integer as php will know what type to use.

Comment: ok my schoolid ```var schoolId = $('#schoolOfficialId').val();``` my ajax data:  ```$.ajax({
                    url: 'load_more.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {schoolId:schoolId},
                    success:function(data){
                        console.log("working");
                    }
                });``` and load_more.php: ```if (isset($_POST['schoolId'])) {
    echo"yesss";
}else {
    echo "nope";
}
``` I still get nope  but console.log logs "working" :(

Comment: Check your console tab and see what it shows when an ajax call is executed. It will have data in different tabs (_especially if you're using Firefox's Firebug_) `post`, `params`, `response` etc. See what's under _post_ tab.

Comment: You know what I found the problem but maybe you can help me since I dont know how to do it. I do the input thing to get the php variable into javascript variable. Now from here my script.js src in the head I try to call the schoolId and it is undefined. even when I put it into aanother variable like ```var schoolId2 = schoolId; the value of schoolId2 is undefined. I even have it with the document.ready function :(

Comment: its not finding schoolId in the script.js is now the issues because it says it is undefined?

Comment: But previously you said it was having the value of `schoolId`. Have you changed anything in the JS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87084/discussion-between-ahmad-baktash-hayeri-and-user4589398).

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is make sure the data reaches your php script.
In your `load_more.php` do this:

```
$school_id = $_POST[schoolId];
var_dump($school_id);
```

rinse and repeat for `last_id`.

Next, if you are using the same php script for different actions, you might want to adjust your logic a bit and consider using this approach:

In each ajax call you send to the php script include at least two parameters, one called "action" or similar, this will be used in your switch case.
another one "value" or similar, which can be your id.
you can add more, if needed, such as limits and offsets.

Example ajax calls:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'load_more.php',
type: 'POST',
data: {param:schoolId,action:"initialCall"},
});

$.ajax({
url: 'load_more.php',
type: 'POST',
data: {param:last_id, limit:limit,action:"loadMore"},
});
```

Example php script

```
// including the config file
require('config.php');
//pdo connct for config.php file
$pdo = connect();

// if POST is not set give a default value for $school_id 
if (!isset($_POST['school_id'])) $school_id = 1;
else $school_id = $_POST[school_id];

//same for action
if (!isset($_POST['action'])) $action = 'initialCall';
else $action = $_POST['action'];

switch ($action) {
  case "initialCall":
     //take action for first ajax call;
    break;

  case "loadMore":
     //take action for second ajax call;
    break;
  default:
     //take default action
    break;
}
```